# Weird Regular Expression (Regex) Matching! Not matching digits

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Ok, this is really really weird. I have the following simple regex search pattern

```
\d*
```

Unfortunately  it doesn't match "7" in

```
*-7d
```

But when I tested the following regex search pattern

```
xx
```

It matchers "xx" in

```
asdxxasd
```

Totally wierd!
BTW, i'm using the normal c# regex object. 
Thanks in advance for any help though!

Sorry, my code is as follows:

```cs
public static string FindFirstRegex(string input,string pattern)
{
    try
    {
        Regex _regex = new Regex(@pattern);
        Match match = _regex.Match(input.ToLower());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return match.Groups[0].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I call the functions as follows:

```
MessageBox.Show(utilities.FindFirstRegex("asdxxasd", "xx"));
MessageBox.Show(utilities.FindFirstRegex("ss327d", "\\d*"));
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Seconding Oli Charlesworth, however you might have forgotten to escape your backslash in the C# regex string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regexp is matching 0 or more digits.  It begins looking at your pattern, and since the first character is a non-digit, it therefore matches zero digits.

If you used + rather than *, you would force it to start at a digit and then (greedily) get the remainder of the digits.

Answer (score 4):

That is because you use `*` quantifier, so `\d*` means digit, any number of repetitions. In .NET implementation this regex for input `*-7d` will return 5 matches: `empty string`, `empty string`, `7`, `empty string` and `empty string`. Use `+` quantifier instead of `*`, i.e.: `\d+`.

Comment: THanks. but why does it return a null?

Comment: @user1034912, Because even empty string will match for `\d*`

Comment: so this is a .NET limitation when it comes to regex?

Comment: @user1034912, I don't know about other implementations, but it's logical behavior.

Comment: It doesn't return null, it returns an empty string.  And it's not a limitation, it's the expected behavior.